# new page created when using the \begin{abstract} command

Tags: document-classes, abstract

I am using emulateapj and am trying to put an abstract in like so:

```
\documentclass{emulateapj}
\setcitestyle{authoryear,round,comma} 
\begin{document}
    \begin{abstract}
        hello world!
    \end{abstract}
\maketitle
\end{document}
```

It is currently creating a pdf with a blank page and then the abstract on the next and there are no errors or warnings. I have cleared the temp files and the problem persists.

(it also puts the title on a new page as well!)

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The class is made to format all of the frontmatter in a particular way, and as such, having just an abstract, it can't print things the way it normally would.  For this particular class, you have to have a section in place before the format can be made the way it is supposed to be.  See the below example for something that would work:

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{emulateapj}

\begin{document}

\title{A \LaTeX\, Example Document}
\author{A. Author}
\date{\today}


\begin{abstract}
This is a sample document which demonstrates some of the basic features
of \LaTeX.  You can easily reformat it for different document or bibliography styles.
\end{abstract}

%Section heading
\section{Introduction}
This file is an example of how to use \LaTeX.  In principle, you only have to worry
about the text content; formatting is taken care of by the options and arguments of
the ``$\backslash$documentclass'' command (other style files are available on the Web.
In practice, however, things are not so simple.  Things like figures and bibliographies 
can go all wrong when you change styles, so expect to have to fiddle!  



\end{document}
```